# how should I store stock for online shopping store products with different size color etc?

Tags: database, e-commerce, erd, online-store, db-schema

I'm designing a database for an online-store.
The store has different kinds of products (different categories: cosmetics, multivitamins, etc)
Each product has different options (color - package size - etc)
this options can effect on the price (like package size) and also each product with specific options varies in stock for example :
golden rose lipstick- color: red - price:50$ -stock: 50
golden rose lipstick- color: red - price:50$ -stock: 70

some kind of multivitamin - package size:60 tabs- price: 60$ -stock:5 
same kind of multivitamin -package size :120 tabs- price:100$-stock:6

how should I design product table to store all options with stocks and price ?
I need a way which would be efficient for filtering products based on their options.

Answer (score 0):

Well just store it like the actual physical products. So treat each size and color like an individual product, because that's what it is. You can also check out how Magento did it in their database. It's good to look at how the competitors do it :)
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-eav-database-structure/